# How to create an appium android device "back button" in java

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

Appium version is: 1.2.0.1

I saw a few codes for that, like:

```
// click back button
HashMap swipeObject = new HashMap();
swipeObject.put("keycode", 82);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", swipeObject);

// click back button
HashMap<String, Integer> keycode = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
keycode.put("keycode", 4);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", keycode);
```

But they don't work , any idea how ?

Comment: You should just read the exception message: `Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html`.

Comment: but my question is how to do so ?

Comment: Your question doesn't reflect that. It looks like you want to use something that is not implemented yet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `driver.navigate().back();` can be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Android device Back button, Please use the below code

**First import the below packages**

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent;
```

**Use the below function**

```
driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.BACK));
```

or

```
((PressesKey) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.BACK));
```

Comment: It worked for me, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
  AndroidDriver driver;
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities=new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","4.2");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","SANJJSKFY899DUCU8MZ");
    //below line wen u want to install - asumming u already installed
    //capabilities.setCapability("app", "D:\\Appium_Udemy\\apk files\\BitbarSampleApp.apk");

    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.bitbar.testdroid");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.bitbar.testdroid.BitbarSampleApplicationActivity");


    driver=new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:5000/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



    driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.RadioButton[@index=1]").click();
    //driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@text()='Please type your name to proceed']").sendKeys("hi manju");
    driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@index=3]").sendKeys("hi manju");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //to press back button of device
    driver.navigate().back();

    //driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@text()='Answer']").click();
    driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@index=0]").click();
```

Comment: Please add an explanation. Don't just post a wall of code.